# Reusing Tanks and Rocket Engines from just beyond Geosynchronus Orbit

Tags: reuse, commercial

There are many Centaur upper stages and a few other objects in the junk yard orbit just beyond the geosynchronous orbit. Is there any reasons why this stuff could not be reused?

There are cryogenic tanks that could eventually serve the oxygen production activities on the moon. There are rocket engines that could be used for landing on and launching from the moon's surface or for space tugs. There are some satellites with solar panels and some interesting electronics. Why isn't anyone talking about all this stuff as an In-Situ Resource?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto, Nothing in the question in Can orbital debris be assembled into a module for space exploration? or in any of the three answers addresses the question presented here.

Comment: It asks about using debris to create an unmanned craft, so that would involve all the parts you mention. An answer points out that due to thermal cycling a lot of these parts would be too damaged to use, another that other sources are more efficient. The answers could stand to be expanded on, I think, but they do apply here.